# Why does the RCC create modern saints?

Tags: catholicism, saint

Why does the RCC create modern saints?
(saints outside the bible)

Some would say God created these saints.But a large part of the church does not find it interesting to give them the  same position in the church as the RCC .

(according to  RCC doctrine)

Comment: Which saints are you referring to?   The veneration of saints long predates the current process of declaring {someone} a saint.  See also [various OT prophets](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/52642/24204) and how the RCC considers them to be saints.  See also [this related Q&A.](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/52902/24204).  Please look at the right hand margin of the page and look at the columns of questions under the heading "Related."

Comment: The RCC doesn't create saints , and it never has.

Comment: Polycarp is regarded as a saint and Church Father in the Eastern Orthodox, Oriental Orthodox, Catholic, Anglican, and Lutheran churches.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A Catholic would say that the church does not "create" saints. Rather, the church's process of canonization is a formal recognition that a particular individual's life has demonstrated extraordinary signs of holiness, so that the church proclaims that the acts or words of that particular individual are deemed to be worthy examples or living individuals to emulate, and that the individual is in heaven blessed to see the beatific vision.

So, in other words, the sainthood is proclaimed,  not created.